# Url pattern matching in chrome for context menus

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, pattern-matching, file-type

Hello I am trying to make a context menu whenever a link to a torrent file has been right clicked. I am trying to create a context menu like this:

```
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Send to seedbox", "contexts":["link"],
                                   "onclick": onTorrentClicked, "documentUrlPatterns":["*://*/*.torrent"]});
```

So the pattern in question is `"*://*/*.torrent"`  It seems like if I have anything but * for the path the pattern always fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting `documentUrlPatterns` you should set `targetUrlPatterns`.

```
..., "targetUrlPatterns":["*://*/*.torrent"]
```

Comment: can you give an example, from what I thought I understood the targetUrlPattern would refer to say, an image the person clicked on the the underlying href link.